# Permitting parameter in devise controller causes UnknownAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm writing a custom form field in a Devise sign up view

```
<%=
    select_tag 'user[show]', options_from_collection_for_select(Show.all, "id", "title")
%>
```

And then, in the registration controller

```
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys:
    [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :show])
end
```

When submitting the form though, I get an error

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'show' for User.):
```

If I don't try permitting the new parameter, and I submit the form, the console logs

```
Unpermitted parameters: show
```

But everything works and I'm able to use those parameters. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column `show_id` in your user table and the select tag is targeting this column:

`<%=
  select_tag 'user[show_id]', options_from_collection_for_select(Show.all, "id", "title")
%>`

And in your controller:

`def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys:
    [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :show_id])
end`